# How to call function for scipy.optimize.fmin_cg(func) in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I will simply explain the problem in short. This problem is exactly similar as shown in [scipy.doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cg.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_cg). The problem is on error occurance as **float argument required, not numpy.ndarray**

**What I have:**

- Function: **y = s*z^t**

**Variable length/dimensions**

- t - 1...m,
- s - 1...m and 1...n. So, m is row number, n - col number.
- z - 1...n.
- y - this can be y[1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cg.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_cg), y[2], y[3],..., y[m],
- T - s[m,n] matrix

**Like this**:

1. `y[1] = s[1][1]*z[1]^t[1]+s[1][2]*z[2]^t[1]+...s[1][n]*z[n]^t[1])`
2. `y[2] = s[2][1]*z[1]^t[2]+s[2][2]*z[2]^t[2]+...s[2][n]*z[n]^t[2])`

   ...
3. `y[m] = s[m][1]*z[1]^t[m]+s[m][2]*z[2]^t[2]+...s[m][n]*z[n]^t[m])`

**Problem:** Error occured.

```
Optimization terminated successfully.

Traceback (most recent call last):
    solution = optimize.fmin_cg(func, z, fprime=gradf, args=args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 952, in fmin_cg
    res = _minimize_cg(f, x0, args, fprime, callback=callback, **opts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 1072, in _minimize_cg
    print "         Current function value: %f" % fval
TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray
```

**Here is the code**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def func(z, *args):
    y,T,t = args[0]
    return y - counter(T,z,t)

def counter(T, z, t):
    rows,cols = np.shape(T)
    res = np.zeros(rows)
    for i,row_val in enumerate(T):
        res[i] = np.dot(row_val, z**t[i])
    return res


def gradf(z, *args):
    y,T,t = args[0]
    return np.dot(t,counter(T,z,t-1))

def main():
    # Inputs
    N = 30
    M = 20
    z0 = np.zeros(N) # initial guess
    y = 30*np.random.random(M)
    T = 10*np.random.random((M,N))
    t = 5*np.random.random(M)
    args = [y, T, t]

    solution = optimize.fmin_cg(func, z0, fprime=gradf, args=args)
    print 'solution: ', solution

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I also tried to find similar examples but could not find something very similar. Here is the code for your consideration. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The root of your problem is that `fmin_cg` expects the function to return a single scalar value for the misfit instead of an array.

Basically, you want something vaguely similar to:

```
def func(z, y, T, t):
    return np.linalg.norm(y - counter(T,z,t))
```

I'm using `np.linalg.norm` here because there's no builtin function in numpy for the root-mean-square.  The actual RMS would be `norm(x) / sqrt(x.size)`, but for minimization the constant multiplier doesn't make any difference.

There are also other minor problems in your code (e.g. `args[0]` is going to be a single item. You want `y, T, t = args` or better yet, just `func(z, y, T, t)`). Your gradient function doesn't make any sense to me, but it's optional regardless. Also, there's no way the solution can produce reasonable values at the moment, as you're testing it against pure noise. I assume those are just meant to be placeholder values, though.

However, you have a larger problem. You're trying to minimize in 30-dimensional space.  Most non-linear solvers aren't going to work well with that high of a dimensionality. It may work fine, but you're very likely to run into problems.

All that having been said, you may find it more intuitive to use the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` interface rather than using the others, if you're okay with LM instead of CG (they're fairly similar methods).

---

One final thing: You're trying to solve for 30 model parameters with 20 observations.  This is an underdetermined problem.  This problem doesn't have a unique solution. You're going to need to apply some a-priori knowledge to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: Kingston: Thanks, but do you think I am searching only one min point? or N? Because, you by using your func() I am getting only one solution whereas I should get N solutions, but I am not sure what you did

Comment: @Spider - No, I think you're searching for 30 model parameters given 20 observations. Your solution should be a 30-item array, but it's going to be unstable (i.e. non-unique).

Comment: @Spider - Also, I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do. What are your knowns and what are your unknowns?

Comment: Kingston- I should have told that. I have only measured data `y` and two coefficients `s`(or `T`), `t` as shown in the code. My unknown is `z`. May be what about changing the coding style, but how? I could not. THanks once again